# APEX Oracle make app public for non-oracle users

Tags: oracle, apex, public

Is it possible to make an APEX app available as a public website? I mean, so that someone without an Oracle account can use the app. If I understand correctly, using No Authentication as the authentication scheme will allow a user to access the app if they have an Oracle Workspace account but, I would like to make the app available to anyone.
Thanks,
Ken

I have tried both No Authentication and for a specific page, under Security, setting it to Page is Public. In both cases, it seems the user still has to login to an Oracle Workspace.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the `Authentication` for a page to `Page is Public` will allow you to access to the page without logging in.

https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/r/adptest/ej-testing/home

[image: APEX Page Designer]

Comment: I'm sorry I'm new at this and I can't figure out how to add my screen shot of my page set to "Page is Public"

Comment: I've set my security to "Page is Public" but it still requires a login when I copy the URL to a different browser

Comment: Maybe I should add that the url redirects to "Oracle Cloud Account Sign In". I don't understand why it redirects?